# Imputing the dataset with mean of class label causing crash in filter operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv file that contains numeric values.

```
val row = withoutHeader.map{
  line => {
  val arr = line.split(',')
  for (h <- 0 until arr.length){
     if(arr(h).trim == ""){
        val abc = avgrdd.filter {case ((x,y),z) => x == h && y == arr(dependent_col_index).toDouble} //crashing here
    arr(h) = //imputing with the value above    
     }
  }
  arr.mkString(",")
  }
}
```

This is a snippet of the code where I am trying to impute the missing values with the mean of class labels.

avgrdd contains the average for the key value pairs where key is column index and the class label value. This avgrdd is calculated using the combiners which I see is calculating the results correctly.

dependent_col_index is the column containing the class labels.

The line with filter is crashing with the null pointer exception.
On removing this line the original array is the output (comma separated).

I am confused why the filter operation is causing a crash.

Please suggest on how to fix this issue.

Example

```
col1,dependent_col_index
4,1
8,0
 ,1
21,1
21,0
 ,1
25,1
 ,0
34,1

mean for class 1 is 84/4 = 21 and for class 0 is 29/2 = 14.5

Required Output
4,1
8,0
21,1
21,1
21,0
21,1
25,1
14.5,0
34,1
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute a RDD transformation inside of another RDD transformation. Remember that you cannot use RDD inside of another RDD transformation, this would cause an error.

The way to proceed is the following:

1. Transform the source RDD `withoutHeader` to the RDD of pairs `<Class, Value>` of the corrent type (Long in your case). Cache it
2. Calculate `avgrdd` on top of `withoutHeader`. This should be an RDD of pairs `<Class, AvgValue>`
3. Join `withoutHeader` RDD and `avgrdd` together - this way for each row you would have a structure `<Class, <Value, AvgValue>>`
4. Execute `map` on top of the result to replace missing `Value` with `AvgValue`

Another option might be to split the RDD in two parts on step 3 (one part - RDD with missing values, second one - RDD with non-missing values), join the `avgrdd` only with the RDD containing only missing values and after that make a union between this two parts. It would be faster if you have a small fraction of missing values