# Handling Missing values in SVM in apache spark ML Lib

Tags: machine-learning, svm, apache-spark-mllib

I have a classification task. I want to use apache spark ml lib SVM algorithm for classification. I have input data which is n-dimensional. In the feature vectors some of dimensions may be missing.

How to approach with missing values? I think it would me wrong to assume missing values as zero or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Right.  ML Lib does not impute missing values, and filling in 0 will skew your results.  However, there is a ReplaceMissingValues package at WEKA that may be of use to you; this implements one of the imputation algorithms.  http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1- omit vectors with missing values
2- Just impute missing values, you can use mean or mode values

I would suggest to do it in spark, is very simple code, here there is an example:

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030101/imputing-the-dataset-with-mean-of-class-label-causing-crash-in-filter-operation)